# Perl tar file creates directory recursively

Tags: perl

I am taring the directory contents using `Archive::Tar` module.

My scripts is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 

use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Tar;
use File::Find;
use Data::Dumper;

my $home_dir = "C:/Users/Documents/Vinod/Perl_Scripts/test/";

my $src_location = $home_dir."LOG_DIR";
my $dst_location = $home_dir."file.tar.gz";

my @inventory = ();
find (sub { push @inventory, $File::Find::name }, $src_location);

print "Files:".Dumper(\@inventory);

my $tar = Archive::Tar->new();

$tar->add_files( @inventory );

$tar->write( $dst_location , 9 );
```

Script is able to create `file.tar.gz` file in location `C:/Users/Documents/Vinod/Perl_Scripts/test/`.

But when I extract the `file.tar.gz` manually it creates a whole path recursively once again. So `LOG_DIR` contents would be visible in the location `C:/Users/Documents/Vinod/Perl_Scripts/test/file.tar/file/Users/Documents/Vinod/Perl_Scripts/test/LOG_DIR/`

How can I have the contents which is inside `C:/Users/Documents/Vinod/Perl_Scripts/test/LOG_DIR/` in `C:/Users/Documents/Vinod/Perl_Scripts/test/file.tar/file/` while extracting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to recreate the full path, [chdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) into the home directory, and make the source dir relative:

```
my $home_dir = "C:/Users/Documents/Vinod/Perl_Scripts/test/";

chdir $home_dir;
my $src_location = "LOG_DIR";
my $dst_location = $home_dir."file.tar.gz";
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you use `$File::Find::name` for your list, you get the absolute path to each file. That's the name that you give `Archive::Tar`, so that's the name that it uses. You can see the files in a tarball:

```
$ tar -tzf archive.tgz
```

There are various ways to get relative paths instead. You might do that in the wanted function. Remove the part of the path that you do not want. That's typically not going to be the directory you used for `find` (`src_location`) because you want to keep that level of structure:

```
my @inventory;
find(
    sub {
        return if /\A\.\.?\z/;
        push @inventory, abs2rel( $File::Find::name, $home_dir )
        }, $src_location
    );
```

Or do it after:

```
@inventory = map { abs2rel($_, $home_dir) } @inventory;
```